# Changing PostgreSQL database parameters for a specific query with PyQGIS

Tags: postgresql, qgis, pyqgis

I'd like to change a specific database setting on a specific Postgresql query in a python script.

I'm using [Postgresql services](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/libpq-pgservice.html) through `QgsDataSourceUri` like i would do with psql:

```
psql "service='dbadmin@gnlpoaura' options='-c random_page_cost=2'" -c 'show random_page_cost;'
```

I tried to pass the parameter using the `setParam` function with the `options` key with no result.

```py
from qgis.core import (
    QgsProject,
    QgsDataSourceUri,
    QgsVectorLayer,
)

uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setParam("service", "myservice")
uri.setParam("options", "-c random_page_cost=1.1")

query = "select row_number() over () as id, name, setting from pg_settings where name like 'random%'"
uri.setDataSource(None, f"({query})", None, "", "id")

data = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "test", "postgres")


print(uri.uri())
print(data.getFeature(1).attributes())
```

Is there a way to configure some postgresql settings on a specific transaction using pyqgis ?

Thanks